# How to use aws role arn in cdk deploy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy my cloud formation stack using aws cdk. 
I want to use different IAM role to deploy my stack as that role has more permissions in aws account.
here is what I am trying

```
cdk deploy -r arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AWSCloudFormationStackSetExecutionRole
```

but I am getting below error

```
No stack found matching '–r'. Use "list" to print manifest
```

Can someone help me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The command is correct. Something else must be happening.

Comment: what does `cdk list` shows?

Comment: @Marcin yes I checked documentation command seems correct.
and cdk list command returns my cdk app name "CreateEbInfraCdkStack"

Comment: you need to supply the stack name. Try "cdk deploy CreateEbInfraCdkStack -r arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AWSCloudFormationStackSetExecutionRole"

Answer (score 3):

Here you need to apply the **-r** (or **--role-name**) option on to cdk itself (and not to the *deploy* option):

```
cdk --role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MY_ROLE_NAME deploy
```

*cdk* will generate a Cloud Formation template and deploy it using the role you specified.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that your cdk cli version thought `-r` as a stack so I think it depends on your cdk version

My cdk version:

```
cdk --version
1.94.1 (build 60d8f91)
```

and it works well with option `-r`

```
cdk deploy -r arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/gitlab-runner 
test-sqs: deploying...
test-sqs: creating CloudFormation changeset...
```

Answer (score -2):

As in [cdk deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tools.html), there is no such option -r. CDK thinks it is a CDK stack name.

I believe you need to use a different IAM role with different IAM permissions. Which has nothing to do with CDK itself. You need to assume role first and get an STS token. Please research assume role AWS CLI of STS.

```
cdk deploy [STACKS..]

Deploys the stack(s) named STACKS into your AWS account

Options:

  --build-exclude, -E    Do not rebuild asset with the given ID. Can be

                         specified multiple times.         [array] [default: []]



  --exclusively, -e      Only deploy requested stacks, don't include

                         dependencies                                  [boolean]



  --require-approval     What security-sensitive changes need manual approval

                         [string] [choices: "never", "any-change", "broadening"]



  --ci                   Force CI detection (deprecated)

                                                      [boolean] [default: false]



  --notification-arns    ARNs of SNS topics that CloudFormation will notify with

                         stack related events                            [array]



  --tags, -t             Tags to add to the stack (KEY=VALUE)            [array]



  --execute              Whether to execute ChangeSet (--no-execute will NOT

                         execute the ChangeSet)        [boolean] [default: true]



  --force, -f            Always deploy stack even if templates are identical

                                                      [boolean] [default: false]



  --parameters           Additional parameters passed to CloudFormation at

                         deploy time (STACK:KEY=VALUE)     [array] [default: {}]



  --outputs-file, -O     Path to file where stack outputs will be written as

                         JSON                                           [string]



  --previous-parameters  Use previous values for existing parameters (you must

                         specify all parameters on every deployment if this is

                         disabled)                     [boolean] [default: true]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. -r is not deploy command option it is cdk command option.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html . Also I tried to change the sequence of deploy and -r but no luck.